# Why my project cannot still be found on Maven center

Tags: maven, deployment, pom.xml, nexus, sonatype

I wanted to deploy my test project to Maven center.
http://search.maven.org/
I followed the steps on the blog:
https://nearsoft.com/blog/deploying-to-maven-central/
It looks all succeeded. The final info is:

> [INFO]  * Upload of locally staged artifacts finished.
> [INFO]  * Closing staging repository with ID "comgithubxiaodongliang->
> 1002".
>
> Waiting for operation to complete...
> ..........
>
> [INFO] Remote staged 1 repositories, finished with success.
>
> [INFO] Remote staging repositories are being released...
>
> Waiting for operation to complete...
> ..............
>
> [INFO] Remote staging repositories released.
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

I can also see the release Artifact on
https://oss.sonatype.org/

But, I cannot find it on Maven center after 5 hours.

is there any more steps to proceed, or I am wrong on the steps above?[image]

Comment: You have to click on "Staging Repositories" and take a look there and click "Release" ...after that it will be synchronized to Maven Cental...But Only releases no SNAPSHOT's..

Comment: @khmarbaise, thank you. It looks "Staging Repositories" does not contain my project. I searched by my group id or name, nothing returned.  anything missed?

Comment: I would suggest first not to autoclose the repo just create it and stage the artifacts and manually check and close it afterwards...maybe you have missed to publish your GPG key...or something else...

Comment: BTW: The sync to maven central can take a longer time ...more than hours usual time is four hours....

Comment: I can see the artifacts in Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.github.xiaodongliang

Comment: @khmarbaise, wow!! it is really there now!! I did nothing but logged a ticket in Jira to ask about this. Thank you much for your input and experience. I think your help made me lucky :) I will follow you guidance to test more.